# How do I loop through a list of files to write to local storage?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, google-cloud-storage

```
Future<void> downloadFiles(url) async {
var result = await getDirectories(url); //this function just returns the path in firestore storage

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
result.items.forEach((firebase_storage.Reference ref) async {
  File downloadToFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/notes/${ref.name}');
  try {
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref(ref.fullPath)
        .writeToFile(downloadToFile);
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
});
```

}

I made this function in flutter to loop through the files in my firebase cloud storage. I have tried writing to local storage with a single file and it works however when I loop through a list of files to write on local storage it doesn't work, it doesn't even produce an error, the code just stops at "foreach" it doesn't even execute the try catch block. Is there a specific function in flutter that writes multiple files to local storage?

Comment: You might need to put await before results.items.forEach

Comment: tried it, it produces an error. It's saying "foreach" is of type "void" so it's value can't be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you are using a `forEach` loop , you will have to use `for` Loop for the your code as below and it will work.

Asynchronous methods doesnt work inside `forEach` Loop

```
    Future<void> downloadFiles(url) async {
            var result = await getDirectories(url); //this function just returns the path in firestore storage
            
            Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            for(int i = 0; i<result.items.length ; i++){
                  File downloadToFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/notes/${result.item[i].name}');
                  try {
                    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
                        .ref(ref.fullPath)
                        .writeToFile(downloadToFile);
                  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
            }
            }
```

Comment: I applied this and it still didn't work looks like my problem is on the google storage side. I'll just post a new question the problem was not in the foreach

Comment: might be but dont use async methods in forEach Loop